# Update Product Prices and Images Using SQL Query

Tags: database, catalog, sql, product-prices

I have about 5k products. I would like to update the sale price and its main image using a query, is this possible?

I'm looking for something like:

```
UPDATE products 
SET 
    sale_price = 25.00, 
    main_image = 'http://source.com/589002200.jpg' 
WHERE sku = 589002200;
```

Comment: The [Magmi Mass Imported tool](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) would be what i would use for this task

Comment: If all the prices and images are gonna be the same, go ahead and do it SQL style. Otherwise, I'd advise you to create a PHP script fetching a collection of products, then looping through them and changing the data you need to change on them then save them. It might take a wee moment, but it's far cleaner than doing it with queries.

Answer (score 1):

**You probably don't want to do this.**

Given you're updating a sale price could you just use the promotions for this?

If you really want to however either use magmi as it's easier or you'll need to dig into the magento EAV database.

Price is stored on the catalog_product_entity_decimal table linked to product ID (called entity_id) and images are stored on in the catalog_product_entity_varchar table.
Not sure if the attribute_id will be the same across stores or not but for images mine are 74 75 76 (for main, small and thumbnail respectively)

I would highly recommend you don't go down this route (if you're unsure), and come up with a better solution, for what you want to do.

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestions and better, your explanation of the database. I might have misspelled my question wrong but the price I wanted to update is the actual price I want to sell the items for.

Comment: Attribute codes are in the table `eav_attribute`. The best way to play around with the database I've found is to have the product open in the admin and make command line queries and soon, patterns begin to emerge. `catalog_product_flat_1` table updates FROM the `catalog_product_entity_*` tables after a reindex or cache or some other magic.